# Using Potlatch 2 with Open Street Maps offline?

Tags: actionscript-3, geolocation, openstreetmap

Does anyone have experience with [Potlatch 2](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Potlatch_2), the Flash client for [openStreetMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org)? I am trying to determine how feasible it might be to hack it to work offline with local data. I saw this question from 6 years ago ([Flash library for OpenStreetMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612444/flash-library-for-openstreetmap/1630397#1630397)) but couldn't find much of anything specifically about customizing Potlatch.

My project involves a presentation tool for displaying saved cellphone data and being able to customize how the data is displayed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you need editing functionality or if you just want to style some existing data. Potlatch2 is primarily an OSM editor, different styling options are not the main focus.

[Umap](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/) might be better suited for your use case. You can also fork it and create your local instance.

Regarding the Potlatch2 offline usage, please a look at the response Richard (potlatch developer) gave some time back: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7735/using-potlatch2-off-line-as-a-teaching-tool

Comment: Thanks – I'll look at UMap.